# updates in telegram bot switch()

Tags: php, webhooks, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I made this code in my .php file where I set webHook that works good.

```php
$token = "my token";
$website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $token . "/";
$updates = file_get_contents("php://input");
$updates = json_decode($updates, true);
$text = $updates["message"]["text"];
$chatID = $updates["message"]["chat"]["id"];

switch($text){
  case "/prova_gratuita":
        if(check($chatID)){
          sendMessage($chatID, "Are you sure? Demo is available only one time. Write confirm to continue");
          switch($text){
            case "confirm":
                 ...
                 break;
          } 
        }
```

Second `switch()` does not work. Why? What can I do?
I know I should update value of `$text`, but I don't know how I can do it

Comment: Why should it work?

Comment: Sorry, I had not completed the question. @u_mulder

Answer (score 0):

I think that the error is how you set up the problem.
Each bot input is a call to that WebHook. Then $ text can not be aggornato that way.

You should also include in the first switch of the "case" of the second.

```
$token = "my token";
$website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $token . "/";
$updates = file_get_contents("php://input");
$updates = json_decode($updates, true);
$text = $updates["message"]["text"];
$chatID = $updates["message"]["chat"]["id"];

switch($text){
    case "/prova_gratuita":
        if(check($chatID))    sendMessage($chatID, "Are you sure? Demo is available only one time. Write confirm to continue");
    case "confirm":
    ...

 }
```

Every time you send a message to the bot, he makes a call to the WebHook. So to change the state of $updates, so even the $text the script should restart

Comment: I understand. Thanks

Comment: Every time you send a message to the bot, he makes a call to the WebHook. So to change the state of $updates, so even the $text the script should restart

Comment: Sisi adesso ci sono arrivato. Grazie di nuovo

Comment: Please, added this also part of the answer :)